# Discontinuity of Greatest Integer Function

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $f(x)$ be an arbitrary function. Let $g(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor$ be the greatest integer function.

We know that $g(x)$ is discontinuous whenever $x$ is integer.

Can we say that $g(f(x)) = \lfloor f(x) \rfloor$ is discontinuous whenever $f(x)$ takes integer values?

Comment: If $f=0$, then $g \circ f = 0$ and so $g \circ f$ is continuous everywhere. If $f(x)=x$ for all $x$, then $g \circ f = g$, and so $g \circ f$ is discontinuous at integer values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a discontinuity when $f$ "crosses" an integer value, not if it reaches it and leaves it "from above".

$\lfloor x^2\rfloor$ is continuous where $x^2=0$.

Comment: ...when $f$ "crosses" an integer value or at least "touches" it from below, like $x\mapsto 1/(1+x^2)$ at zero

Comment: @CiaPan: no, $\lfloor\frac1{1+x^2}\rfloor$ is not continuous at $x=0$. (If this is what you mean.)

Comment: Exactly. You said 'There is a _dis_continuity when...' and I expand the criterion for $f$ which makes the $\lfloor f\rfloor$ discontinuous, hence the example. This is a function which "touches" an integer $f=1$ from below but does not "cross" it, anyway it results in $g\circ f$ discontiniuous.

Comment: @CiaPan: ok, in fact my answer does not cover all cases, you are right.

Answer (score 9):

No, we can't. If $f$ is constant then $g \circ f$ is constant and hence continuous.

By the way it's easy to characterize all functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $g \circ f$ is continuous. We have
$$g \circ f \quad \text{cont.}\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad g \circ f \quad \text{const.}\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \exists k \in \mathbb Z, f(\mathbb R) \subseteq [k,k+1).$$

Comment: What if f(x) isn't constant?

Comment: @GulshanMishra Then $g \circ f$ might still be continuous.

Comment: @GulshanMishra: What if $f(x)=0.1$ for $x\ge0$, but $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$?

Comment: @GulshanMishra Or consider $f(x)=(1+\sin(x))/\pi$.

Comment: @GulshanMishra: If $f$ and $g$ are both continuous (on $\Bbb{R}$), then $f \circ g$ is continuous. But the converse is not true: $f \circ g$ can be continuous without $f$ or $g$ needing to be continuous.

Comment: Nice generalization of my (counter)example. :)

Comment: @CiaPan Which generalization do you mean?

Comment: I mean you saying 'all $f$ such that...' instead of my 'let's test $f$ being a sine squared'.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *can* say it, but that wouldn't be true in general.

Let $f(x)=\sin^2 x$, then $f$ is integer at all integer multiples of $\pi$.

However,
$$(g\circ f)(x)=\begin{cases}
  1 & \text{for }x=(2k+1)\pi, k\in\mathbb Z \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
so it's discontinuous at odd multiples of $\pi$ only.